# How to save file to internal storage on Android 10

Tags: java, android-studio

Recently I made an application that can save files that have been generated to internal storage.
I run on Android 9 does not have a problem, but on Android 10, the file cannot be exported. is there a solution to overcome this?

Answer (score -2):

You can just call `new File(YourDir)` and it will store on the app specified storage

Comment: Can you explain the permissions that are required to allow the creation of new files? Android 10 introduced several new privacy policies that constraint the use of shared storage